# Methodologies for Managing Users and Access?

Tags: design-patterns, database, users, access-control

This is something I'm having a hard time getting my head around. I think I might be making it more complicated than it is.

What I'm trying to do is develop a method to store users in a database with varying levels of access, throughout different applications. I know this has been done before, but I don't know where to find how they did it.

Here is an example of what I need to accomplish:

```
UserA - Access to App1, App3, App4 & can add new users to App3, but not 4 or 1. 
UserB - Access to App2 only with ReadOnly access.
UserC - Access to App1 & App4 and is able to access Admin settings of both apps.
```

In the past I've just used user groups. However, I'm reaching a phase where I need a bit more control over each individual user's access to certain parts of the different applications. I wish this were as cut and dry as being able to give a user a role and let each role inherit from the last.

Now, this is what I need to accomplish. But, I don't know any methods of doing this. I could easily just design something that works, but I know this has been done and I know this has been studied and I know this problem has been solved by much better minds than my own.

This is for a web application and using sql server 2008. I don't need to store passwords (LDAP) and the information I need to store is actually very limited. Basically just username and access.

Comment: I don't know enough about your business model, but I wouldn't get away from groups even if it meant several groups currently only had one member. People come and go. It's easier to add a new user and assign to the same groups as the person they replace than trying to find all of a specific user's settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the setup in the application I maintain:

- active directory has groups which can access the application with users in each group
- fine grained permissions are held in tables linked to groups so that all IT has to do is to add a user to an Active directory group
- a buggy service that synchronizes Active Directory users to a table of application users

you need

- Users table: with name, userId (numeric), enabled (numeric) and whatever users sign on with. (Usually a text string like your initials)
- Role Table: Active Directory groups with numeric ID and text identifier
- Action Table: group your permissions by type: access to Applications, access to Administrative, can grant permissions. create a table for each with numeric identifier and descriptive string.
  In the application I maintain top level permissions include ACCESS the master application, GRANT permissions, READ, UPDATE, ACCESS a linked sub application
- so a query to see what groups have top level permissions looks like this

  SELECT   cr.NAME "AD_Group",
              CR.ID GROUP_ROLE_ID,
              DECODE (a.NAME,
                      'APPROVE', 'Approve Organizations',
                      'CONTACTS', 'Contact information',
                      'GRANT', 'Grant permissions',
                      a.NAME)
                 "Stage/Permission",
              gp.role_id,
              gp.action_id,
       FROM   action a,
              general_permission gp,
              role cr
      WHERE   a.ID = gp.action_id
              AND gp.role_id = cr.ID

When your user logs on you query LDAP for what groups that they are a member of. Then query the database for what permissions the groups have.  Make it easy on yourself and make permissions additive.

Comment: Good answer.  I don't believe the OP needs the Active Directory aspects, but including AD in your answer doesn't change the fundamentals of what needs to be done.